# Jacobian on MATLAB does not work with specific equation

Tags: matlab

I have to solve the following system on MATLAB:

`(x1^3)-(x1^2)*(x2)=-12 (1)`

`2*(x1^2)+3\*(x1)-(x2)=9 (2)`

I started by creating a function and it worked with other equations, but not with (1) and (2) whem i use the command Point1_Q3:

`function [xsol1,xsol2] =NewRaph2(F1,F2,F11,F22,F12,F21,x1i,x2i,iter,Err)`

`%Cette fonction sert à résoudre le système d’équations non-linéaires`

`%Inputs: %F1: first equation`
`%F2: second equation`
`%F11 : derivative F1(x1)`
`%F22 : derivative F2(x2)`
`%F12 : derivative F1(x2)`
`%F21 : derivative F2(x1)`
`%x1i : initial value of x1`
`%x2i : initial value of x2`
`%iter : n iteration`
`%Err : error rel`
`%xsol1 : value of x1`
`%xsol2 : value of x2`

`for i=1:iter;`

`jacobien=F11(x1i,x2i)*F22(x1i,x2i)-F21(x1i,x2i)*F12(x1i,x2i);`

`x1delt=(-F1(x1i,x2i)*F22(x1i,x2i)+F2(x1i,x2i)*F12(x1i,x2i))/jacobien;`

`x2delt=(-F2(x1i,x2i)*F11(x1i,x2i)+F1(x1i,x2i)*F21(x1i,x2i))/jacobien;`

`x11=x1i+x1delt;`

`x21=x2i+x2delt;`

`Errx1=abs((x11-x1i)/x1i);`

`Errx2=abs((x21-x2i)/x2i);`

`if Errx1<Err && Errx2<Err`

`xsol1=x11;`

`xsol2=x21;`

`break`

`else`

`x1i=x11;`

`x2i=x21;`

`end`

`end`

`` end` ``
Script command Point1_Q3

`F1=@(x1,x2) 12+(x1^3)-(x1^2)`*`(x2);`*

*`F2=@(x1,x2) -9+2`*`(x1^2)+3*(x1)-(x2);`

`F11=@(x1,~) 3*(x1^2)-(2`*`x1`*`x2);`

`F22=@(~,x2) -1;`

`F12=@(~,x2) -1*(x1^2);`

`F21=@(x1,~) 4*(x1)+3;`

`x1i=-2.84;`

`x2i=-1.36;`

`Err=0.00001;`

`iter=100;`

`[xsol1,xsol2]=NewRaph2(F1,F2,F11,F22,F12,F21,x1i,x2i,iter,Err)`

I expect Point1_Q3 to give me [xsol1,xsol2], but i get this error:

`Unrecognized function or variable 'x2'.`

`Error in @(x1,~)3*(x1^2)-(2`*`x1`*`x2)`

`Error in NewRaph2 (line 19)`
`jacobien=F11(x1i,x2i)*F22(x1i,x2i)-F21(x1i,x2i)*F12(x1i,x2i);`

Comment: `@(x1,~)3*(x1^2)-(2 x1 x2)`  is not valid MATLAB code. You appear to be missing some operators or other formatting.

Comment: There look to a number of other errors in the code, including how you’re defining anonymous functions without, for example, `x2` as an argument  or as a variable previously defined in the code.